# using menuconfig to enable a driver as a module

Tags: yocto

I'm using the Yocto Project- Dunfell to create a custom Image for my target.
The goal is to enable the IGC driver (Ethernet driver developed by intel) as a module (.ko) so it will be dynamic, loading an unloading from the kernel for testing purposes.

I am using the command:

```
$ devtool modify linux-intel
$ devtool menuconfig linux-intel
```

Then I choose the driver and mark it as 'M', save and exit.
then I try to build my image again using bitbake

```
$ bitbake x86-image-core
```

Then I run the Image using qemu/target but can't find the .ko file.

what are to correct steps for enabling that driver as a module?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following bitbake command to open Linux kernel menuconfig GUI. In this, you can do it easily, like on this ["How to customize the Linux Kernel" article](https://architechboards-pengwyn-v100.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernel.html) show it. Note that, not all kernel component can be `M` which mean it will be a `.ko` module, menuconfig will let it to use `M` or not for your driver.

```
bitbake -c menuconfig linux-intel
```